# Gap(white Space) is coming between Slider and Footer Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Slider div and a footer Div in my web page.The problem that i am facing with these two divs is that So much of WhiteSpace (Gap) is coming Which i dont Want.I am trying to place another Div in between the Two present right now but the problem of the gap is same.

Here is my HTML ..

```
 <div class="skdslider">
 // Slider HTML
 </div>

 <div id="footer" class="footer-shadow">
 //Footer HTML
 </div>
```

And here is the fiddle that i have created .Please see it..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/xouyqpqv/1/)

Please help me to resolve this .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what it's for, but by removing the following CSS:

```
.skdslider:after {
    content: '';
    padding-top: 50%; 
    display: block;
}
```

The gap is non-existant.

So, if that `:after` is not needed, I would remove it!

Comment: If i am removing padding-top:50% it is reducing my Slider Height .And All the images are getting collapsed

Comment: Will You please check into the fiddle.I want to keep the slider height as it is and remove Whietespace only..

Comment: I've checked the fiddle. The problem is that you're setting heights in percentages. Without images I'm not sure what the height should be. Can you make an example with images? Do the images vary in height?

Comment: The height of the images are `860px`  I am trying to make it responsive so that it can take any image size

Comment: It looks like you're calling the function to an actual container it provides (`.skdslider`), so it's getting wrapped twice, and the second container is the problem.

Comment: Reading about the plugin now. I would assume you could rename the container's class you have in fiddle to whatever or just remove it but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned this in the comments - you have duplicate `.skdslider` containers, so it's getting wrapped twice, and the second container's :after is the problem.

Comment: Yeah just remove your '<div class="skdslider"></div>' container - you provide what it needs @ ' jQuery('#demo1').skdslider({ ...  });' and it creates this container for you.

Comment: You want to me to remove this from .css filr

Comment: Negative - remove it from the actual HTML. So you only have markup for '<ul id="demo1" class="slides"> ... </ul>'

Comment: Take a peek @ http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/pvxa4trb/ let me know if that works!

Comment: Ok is it possible to keep <div class="skdslider"></div> this and remove other container because .My other css is getting collapsed drastically if i am removing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58884/discussion-between-user3816352-and-evan).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing that 50% to 47.5% and 49% respectively to get a reasonable gap below the slider.

```
.skdslider:after {
    content: '';
    padding-top: 47.5%; 
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .skdslider:after {
        padding-top: 49%;
    }
}
```